# Tomcat running, port 80 connection refused error

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, curl, amazon-ec2, permission-denied

At first, everything was fine, until today. My site (running on Apache Tomcat) gave a No Data Received error page in Chrome. I panicked, and tried port 8080. It worked. Port 80 was failing. So I tried doing SSH to my EC2 Instance, and restarting tomcat. The restart worked, but my site still failed. I tried using `sudo curl localhost:80` on my instance (Ubuntu Linux AMI), and I got this error: `curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:80; Connection refused`. What does it mean, and more importantly, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: How are you proxying port 80 to port 8080?

Comment: Well, I don't exactly know :D My system admin set it up, but I have root (admin) SSH access to everything. The weird thing is, I set up a new empty instance with tomcat on it. I tried `curl localhost:80` when tomcat ran on port 8080, and got the exact same error... And I din't change anything at all..

Comment: Often if you are running Tomcat on port 80, you are proxying through a web server (Apache, nginx, etc.). It may be that your webserver failed.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often if you are running Tomcat on port 80, you are proxying through a web server (Apache, nginx, etc.). It may be that your webserver failed.
(as posted by @datasage)